# Chromecast for Android MediaRouter getInstance() causing crash

Tags: android, chromecast

So I have been following along with this tutorial: http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/developing-chromecast-ready-application-android-platform

I have done everything up to and including 2.3.3 part 1.  My app comes to a login activity first and then launches into the main activity.  I want the Chromecast button to be displayed only in the main activity.   My app is crashed when it tries to launch the MainActivity.

I have this in OnCreate():

```
    Log.d("Chromecast", "first");
    mediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    Log.d("Chromecast", "second");
    mediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder().addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast("myappID")).build();
    Log.d("Chromecast", "made it here");
```

My app never reaches the second Log call.

The crash I am receiving is:

> 09-17 16:06:40.993: W/dalvikvm(27276): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3549 (mr_user_route_category_name) in Landroid/support/v7/mediarouter/R$string;
>
> 09-17 16:06:41.009: W/dalvikvm(27276): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4171dd40)

Does anyone know what is going on?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including the android-support-v7-mediarouter libary in your project. The framework of MediaRouter will not work. Also, take a look at the Cast Companion Library which will do most of the work for integrating Cast into an Android app: 
https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I am including the support-v7-mediarouter library. I will look into that link.